# Microstation coordinates in Google Earth

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, google-earth, microstation

I have got this x,y,z values of a cell(point feature) from microstation, I am trying to locate it in Google Earth. This is the location from London UTM zone 30U. I have tried it too.

> 530563.1906, 178968.2347, 5.8100 (z value)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To convert UTM coordinates into geographic latitude + longitude coordinates (WGS84), you can use an online tool such as [this one](http://home.hiwaay.net/~taylorc/toolbox/geography/geoutm.html).  In your case, "30U" means zone 30 in the northern hemisphere, and using this tool, you should get a latitude + longitude of 1.619158, -2.725228.  The Z coordinate is mostly irrelevant here as it is just the height in metres above sea level.

It is also possible to use UTM coordinates directly in Google Earth, under *Tools* > *Options…* > *Show Lat/Long* > *Universal Transverse Mercator*.  After selecting this option, when adding new placemarks, the UTM coordinates may be specified.

However, I believe it is most likely that your coordinates are not actually in the UTM 30U coordinate system, since 1.619158, -2.725228 is in the middle of the ocean, very close to the WGS84 origin.  In Great Britain, one of the most common coordinate systems used is the Ordnance Survey National Grid, or "EPSG:27700".  If you use an online conversion tool such as [this one](http://www.bgs.ac.uk/data/webservices/convertForm.cfm#bngToLatLng), you should get a latitude + longitude of 51.494587, -0.120628, which seems more reasonable as this point is in the middle of London.  Unfortunately, Google Earth does not have built-in support for Ordnance Survey National Grid coordinates.

Comment: confirming 51.4945869877305,-0.120628516589673 via http://www.nearby.org.uk/coord.cgi?p=530563.1906%2C178968.2347&f=full#llTQ3056378968 map https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/51%C2%B029'40.5%22N+0%C2%B007'14.3%22W/@51.4946049,-0.1206643,84m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d51.494587!4d-0.1206285

Comment: @candy-gumdrop Thanks for you brief explanation..Now I can able to see where I failed.

Comment: Yes @mapperz location is exactly correct!